# How can I center left floated items in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below code in my `style.css` file which results in my grid/box items displaying to the left of the webpage, as per these examples:

[image: Mobile Phone View]
[image: Laptop View]

As you can see, these float to the left but I really want them to be centered. 
I've tried removing the `float: left` and putting `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center` and other variations which didn't work.

What do I need to change to make it work?

```
.GRID
width:170px;
height:235px;
background:#f4f4f4;
border:1px solid #dedede;
padding:4px;
border-radius:4px;
text-align: center;
float:left;
margin:9px;
margin-bottom:20px;
position:relative

.XOX
display: block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-top: 0px; 
overflow:hidden

.widget-container
{
text-align:left
}

.widget-container ul { padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none }
.widget-container ul li { margin-bottom:6px; }
```

Comment: Can you add your html markup in here ?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for you question

Comment: The HTML info is: <div class="<?php echo $class_main ?>">
     <ul class="XOX">
            
            <li class="widget-container latest-posted">
          <?php
    
     include 'latest-posted.php'; 
    
    ?>
         </li>
            <li class="widget-container latest-posted2">
          <?php
    
     include 'latest-posted2.php';
    
    ?>
         </li>

Comment: you can copy the html from the firebug in firefox or similiar from other browsers or simply extract the html from the view page source

Comment: A full page example is at - http://www.yossca.com/ - the boxes float left but nothing I'm doing is making them center.

Comment: Put `text-align:center;` on `.xoxo>li`, and remove floats from your `.grid_task` and add `display:inline-block;` to them. You are centering elements *within* the container, that's why the container needs to have the text centering option.

Answer (score 0):

If the grids are what you want to center, try using `margin: auto;` if you haven't already in the `.GRID` selector. I'd remove your other margins before trying the first time to get a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your HTML looks like

but here is a simple way of centering content inside a div
Heres a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/78fmrtz4/

---

### EDIT

After looking through your site you can simply fix this, by changing styles to:

```
.widget-container { text-align: center; }
.widget-container .widget-title { text-align:left; }
```

that is causing you issues, you should rather add that just to the title element that you want left, also on a side not you could achieve this without using floats and just having set widths, note you will have to cater for the margins you have set,

```
<style type="text/css">
.widget-container {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:red;
}
.widget-container > ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none outside none;
    width:100%;
}
.widget-container > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    width:30%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:magenta;
}
</style>

<div class="widget-container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#foo" title="Link to foo">&nbsp;
            <img="http://yourdomain.co/assets/img.png" alt="ALT TEXT">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#foo" title="Link to foo">&nbsp;
            <img="http://yourdomain.co/assets/img.png" alt="ALT TEXT">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#foo" title="Link to foo">&nbsp;
            <img="http://yourdomain.co/assets/img.png" alt="ALT TEXT">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: After all of that, I am still having problems centering the boxes/containers. Here is another site using the same theme - www.helpme.ae - when you view the page on a mobile phone, the 'Latest Posted Tasks' floats to the left. It would look so much nicer if they could be centered but everything I've tried has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you set your col

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
```

meaning that you can't achieve the centering positioning. There's a way to make your col in center without edit your css.

I using offset to make you col in center.

To know more about offset click the link that i provide http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Before

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
```

Replace the before with

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6">
```

Result

[image]

Comment if got any question. Thanks.

Comment: Am getting closer to what I want but the above still doesn't center when viewing it on a mobile phone - it only centers on a wide screen. I'm not too concerned with centering it on wide screen as it displays five boxes on one line so it already looks perfect. But when viewing it on a mobile phone, it only fits one box per line (which floats left) so I mainly want to center this view.

Comment: Before u want to make your widget container display in inline-block, You need to fix your media query first. I found out there is huge white empty display. 
If you still want the inline-block. Try delete the div who has class with the main. `<div class="main">`

Answer (score 0):

if you want your output to look like the screen below [image]

Then simply try adding the following css

```
.grid_task{
left: 15%;
position: relative;
}
```